# Use a closure instead of a `thisArg`? Issue with .pipe(map(

Tags: typescript, rxjs

The code I have is marked deprecated, I'm wondering if anyone could help me update it.

The issue is with the map part.

/** @deprecated Use a closure instead of a `thisArg`. Signatures accepting a `thisArg` will be removed in v8. */

```
public getDetails(): any 
  {
    return this.apiService.findForm().pipe(map((response: any) => {

      return response;
    },
      err => {

        return err;
      }
    ));
  }
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Separating the two arguments to map fixes this:

```
return this.apiService.findForm()
  .pipe(
     map((response: any) => { return response; }),
     catchError((err) => { return err; })
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

As I can see in rxjs code, as long as you don't use the map with the second signature, this deprecation doesn't concern you.

```
export function map<T, R>(project: (value: T, index: number) => R): OperatorFunction<T, R>;
/** @deprecated Use a closure instead of a `thisArg`. Signatures accepting a `thisArg` will be removed in v8. */
export function map<T, R, A>(project: (this: A, value: T, index: number) => R, thisArg: A): OperatorFunction<T, R>;
```